# JQuery Mobile and Firefox don't play well together?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

Having some teething issues with jQuery Mobile. Was wondering if anybody else is experiencing a smattering of errors when they're using Firefox (desktop) and have the jQuery Mobile script includes in their `<head>` like so:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
```

In both Chrome and Firefox I get a host of CSS errors, which I presume are negligible. But in Firefox I get a couple of JS errors on top of that, which also seems to break my page (responsive elements not rendering like they would when I remove the jQuery Mobile script).

The JS errors:

```
Empty string passed to getElementById(). @ http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.js:11100
Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead. @ http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js:3346
```

I know the errors seem pretty verbose, but I'm not familiar with bloaty javascript plugins and their policy on graceful degradation. Anyone else having this issue?

**Update**

As per Tim's answer, I've snapshotted evidence that these jQuery Mobile 'warnings' are actually effecting the page. Below is the page when I comment the jQuery Mobile script tags out:

[image: Without jQuery Mobile]

And here is what the page looks like when the jQuery Mobile script tags are left in:

[image: With jQuery Mobile]

Note that the reason I wanted to use jQuery Mobile is purely for it's mobile touch/swipe events. I have no interest in adopting it's hash/ajax linking functionality.

Comment: The line numbers provided are the ones that suggested the error. Use your browser's "stack trace" feature to find places where your own code is causing these problems.

Comment: @Brian I've removed all of my own JavaScript and the errors still remain, so it's not my code that's breaking it...

Comment: [do you run any firefox extensions that conflict with these two scripts?](http://i.imgur.com/UKX7uLF.png)

Comment: @Brian I don't use Firefox (just testing with it), so it's a clean install as far as I can see. No 'extensions', and some vanilla plugins that were there on install (see edited question for image). I've also just removed everything except the two scripts and a body (like your example) and the errors are still being thrown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, jQuery Mobile does "mess with the DOM" when it's loaded.  For example, jQuery Mobile will wrap your content in a "page" div:

> Behind the scenes, the framework will inject the page wrapper if it's
>   not included in the markup because it's needed for managing pages
>   ([Pages - jQuery Mobile Docs](http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/dist/demos/widgets/pages/))

But you could see if it's the CSS or the Javascript that's breaking your site by including only one of the jQuery Mobile bits at a time.

I too am getting the same warning regarding the call to `getElementById()`, and I can confirm that it is just a warning and does not impact layout.  [I have asked specifically about getting rid this warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18462974/how-to-remove-empty-string-passed-to-getelementbyid-warning?noredirect=1#comment27836571_18462974), but to no avail.

Finally, have you tried using [jQuery Mobile's custom builder](http://jquerymobile.com/download-builder/) to get just the parts you are interested in (i.e. the touch features)?

Comment: Yup. jQuery Mobile had hijacked my DOM with a load of classes and some divs. Firefox is a lot more affected by wrapping elements than Chrome seems to be. They seem to interpret the box model differently, especially in regards to height.

Answer (score 4):

What Firefox is giving you are warnings, not errors :)

Taking a look at the [jQuery Mobile source](http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.js) :

```
// find present pages
var path = $.mobile.path,
    $pages = $( ":jqmData(role='page'), :jqmData(role='dialog')" ),
    hash = path.stripHash( path.stripQueryParams(path.parseLocation().hash) ),
    hashPage = document.getElementById( hash );
```

Setting a breakpoint on that line using the Chrome Development Tools (Firefox and Firebug seemed unable to load the entire script), we can see that `path.parseLocation().hash` will be nothing when there is no hash in the URL, so `document.getElementById( hash )` will throw the warning you saw in Firefox.

If it bothers you, you can turn off warnings in the Firefox Development Console, but if you're going to use jQuery Mobile I'm afraid the warning will be displayed for URL's with no hash.  It isn't Firefox trying to tell you something IS wrong, it's just Firefox telling you something COULD be wrong, which is not true in this case.

Regarding the other warning, [this discussion](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/pull/1294) might be useful.  It seems jQuery uses the deprecated `getPreventDefault()` for compatibility with Android 2.3.

Comment: Apologies for my sloppy semantics. They are indeed warnings, but they are not negligible due to the fact that they are producing a broken page. Please see updated question for comparable images. Unless the warnings themselves have nothing to do with the bad page, and I need to look elsewhere for answers. Does jQuery Mobile mess with the DOM/CSS when loaded? If so, why and how?

Comment: I am positive those warnings are not breaking your page, but yes jQM does mess with things when it is loaded.  Maybe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10840387/1091751) and [this discussion](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/2283) can help you out.

Comment: Surely, this particular part of the problem could easily be tested by appending a hash to the end of your URL.  Then you could see if that just gets rid of this "warning", or is the cause of your larger issues.

Comment: @Strings agreed, also it's not really possible to troubleshoot the problem further without seeing any code from the page in question.

Comment: I've given the answer to Mathew I'm afraid. Although this was helpful, Mathew's answer was the one that made me go and give the DOM a closer look. Indeed, jQuery Mobile had injected some of it's bunk into my webpage (without so much as a call to the script). Have +1'd you though. :-)

Answer (score 0):

My stuff often gets thrown out of format when using Firefox (many other small bugs too)  If its just for testing, I suggest Google Chrome or Safari for best performance...

Comment: ...I wouldn't test on a platform that I wasn't planning to put into production...

Comment: oh, by your comments i thought you weren't going to use firefox

Comment: I know you came to answer, not to ask, but my advice would be to take Firefox seriously as a widely-used vendor; even if it's not your favourite browser.

Comment: I just used chrome to test my jqm + phonegap android app, everything works the same, however the cordova functions do not work (obviously)