# jQuery Mobile breaks links. What is the correct use?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, hyperlink

I added jQuery Mobile to my project because I want swipe events to trigger Bootstrap carousel scrolls. After coding with it for a day or so I noticed that internal links no longer work. 
I can reproduce this reliably with the following two pages, test1.html:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <a href="test2.html">Another page</a>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile.min.js">
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

and test2.html:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <a href="test1.html">First page</a>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
  </script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile.min.js">
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I click the link, jQuery code will throw a handled exception that is swallowed, but the target page never loads in the browser. When I remove jQuery Mobile, it works in a normal way.

I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10837759/jquery-mobile-breaks-my-site) - adding `data-ajax="false"` does seem to fix the issue, but is this really necessary? What's the point of jQuery Mobile then?

`$.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false` did not do anything. I also came across [this discussion](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/2283) on Github and had hopes that the issue only happened when linking to non-jQuery Mobile pages, but it does not.

Comment: May be you are missing the whole point of jQuery Mobile; it's whole navigation system is ajax driven. Turn ajax off and you are left with a lifeless regular site. The smallest building block is a page. So without a page in your markup, I won't even begin to answer your question. And I don't see the css either!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is something unique to jQuery Mobile.

First you are missing one big information, never mix jQuery Mobile with other frameworks, if you only need to use just one functionality. In that case you should customize jQuery Mobile and use/build only needed functionality. Find it [**here**](http://jquerymobile.com/download-builder/).

In your case you are using full jQuery Mobile framework and it will overtake your complete project. jQuery Mobile uses **AJAX** to handle page management, which means it will load pages into the **DOM** to make them run as smooth as possible.

When working with with multiple **HTML** template only first **HTML** file is fully loaded into the **DOM**. When you open another page jQuery Mobile will strip **HEAD** and load only div with **data-role="page"** attribute, because you don't have such div page transition will fail.

When you disable **AJAX** loading **data-ajax="false"** attribute you will force jQuery Mobile to use classic page handling.

Basically just follow my first advice and rebuild jQuery Mobile using only functionality you really need. Use full jQuery Mobile framework only if you intend to use it as UI framework and nothing else, never ever.

Feel free to ask me if you need more information.